# WebStorm overwrites process.env in Node.js

Tags: node.js, process, webstorm

Starting my Node.js application in WebStorm, the process.env object is overwritten by WebStorm.

[image: Webstorm server start button]

The process.env object looks like this:

```
{ SystemRoot: 'C:\\Windows' }
```

I have no environment variables defined in WebStorm.

[image]

Starting my application in the WebStorm console [node server.js] everything is working fine. The process.env looks like this:

```
{ PROCESSOR_LEVEL: '6',
  FP_NO_HOST_CHECK: 'NO',
  PROMPT: '$P$G',
  SESSIONNAME: 'Console',
  ALLUSERSPROFILE: 'C:\\ProgramData',
  PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: 'AMD64',
  ...}
```

The problem is, that WebStorm overwrites the whole process.env. Is there a way to prevent WebStorm overwriting my process.env-object?

Comment: How did you define it?

Comment: @lena I didn't define any variable (see edited Post).

Comment: please check if 'Include parent environment variables' is enabled in your server.js run configuration - press ellipsis button next to 'Environment variables' field and see if this checkbox is ticked

Comment: @lena: Great, that did it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by ticking the checkbox for "Include parent environment variables" in the environment variables section of configuration edit.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could set your environment value within the [Run/Debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/run-debug-configuration-node-js.html) configuration to ensure that they are set to the appropriate values when you run it via Webstorm.

Comment: thanks, but thats exactly the problem. I haven't defined anything and webstorm is still overwriting the whole process.env object.